# Stop <Super> key from resizing windows

Tags: unity, 16.04, shortcut-keys, mouse, unity-dash

Not sure when this started happening but at some point just taping (Super)  will place my mouse in the middle of the current application window and will go into resizing mode.

This is not (Alt)+click resizing, that will keep the mouse in its current location.

When tapping (Super) I don't need to click at all, and it still goes into resizing mode.

This is really frustrating because I use (Super) a lot for opening the dash, and now that it does this resizing thing I can no longer open the dash with the key.

Opening the dash can work still, the mouse just can't be over any application windows, i.e. on empty desktop space.

(Alt)+click works just as it should. If `mouse-button-modifier` is set to (Super), then the middle click option will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using CCSM

Open ccsm or CompizConfig-SettingsManager.

Go to **Resize Window** Plugin

On the **Bindings** tab, You'll see two icons, one is a mouse, another is keyboard icon.

Click on the clear button next to the value  for the keyboard icon.

That will reset the settings

#### Using terminal

Or use this command in a terminal to reset this to default <kbd>Alt-F8</kbd>

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-resize [\'\<Alt\>F8\']
```

Comment: this fixed it thanks! Curious though, I had to install CCSM to do this. How would this have been set if CCSM wasn't already installed?

Comment: @tamato No idea. may be some other applications sets this or accidentally happened

Comment: Is there place to see the list of schemes / keys of gsettings that give a description of them? Google isn't helping.

Comment: I used `gsettings list-recursively | grep resize` to find this